# Symfony2 remove id field from submitted form data

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony2-forms

My Symfony2 form has a text field containing the entity's ID.

I used the following to achieve this:

```
$formBuilder->add('id', TextType::class, ['attr' => ['readonly' => true]])
```

When submitting the form, which represents an existing entity, the ID is passed and Doctrine searches for an accessor method to modify the ID. At this point, an exception is thrown, as the entity doesn't allow to change the ID.

What is the common way in Symfony2 to provide a read-only field, which is not meant to be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readonly` is for clients. It indicates that client can't change the value of the element. But it is going to be submitted with form.

If you don't want element's value to be submitted use `disabled` instead.

Comment: Yes, I didn't expect readonly to have any effect on the server side. But I didn't know about "disabled", because I only looked in the general form documentation, whereas it can be found in the TextType-documentation